# Isovalue in Marching Cubes Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, opengl, cubes

I was reading the article here: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/.

Currently, I have a minecraft like terrain generated using simplex noise which I divided into 16x16 chunks that has a 32x32x128 blocks. Now, I want to use the noise I generated to the Polygonise function in marching cubes. But my problem is how can I compute the isovalue? I don't get it.

Anyone here knows a much more spoonfeed article. lol

EDIT:

Hey I found this on http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/marchingsource.cpp.

sSourcePoint[] has a value of 0.5, so it just center the object but what does the fResult += 0.5/(fDx*fDx + fDy*fDy + fDz*fDz) does? Omg, I'm intimidated with the codes.

```
GLfloat fSample1(GLfloat fX, GLfloat fY, GLfloat fZ)
{
        GLdouble fResult = 0.0;
        GLdouble fDx, fDy, fDz;
        fDx = fX - sSourcePoint[0].fX;
        fDy = fY - sSourcePoint[0].fY;
        fDz = fZ - sSourcePoint[0].fZ;
        fResult += 0.5/(fDx*fDx + fDy*fDy + fDz*fDz);

        fDx = fX - sSourcePoint[1].fX;
        fDy = fY - sSourcePoint[1].fY;
        fDz = fZ - sSourcePoint[1].fZ;
        fResult += 1.0/(fDx*fDx + fDy*fDy + fDz*fDz);

        fDx = fX - sSourcePoint[2].fX;
        fDy = fY - sSourcePoint[2].fY;
        fDz = fZ - sSourcePoint[2].fZ;
        fResult += 1.5/(fDx*fDx + fDy*fDy + fDz*fDz);

        return fResult;
}
```

Comment: You do not _compute_ the isovalue; you _set_ the isovalue. The volume is implicitly defined by `f(x,y,z) = isovalue` where `f` is a scalar 3D field (the noise). You'll need to define somehow values on points, not blocks.

Comment: thanks. that helped a lot. Now, I'm trying to understand some of the codes in http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/marchingsource.cpp. I found the fSample1 which I think give the points. But I don't understand it fully. How did he managed to create 3 objects with just returning only a float?

Comment: The `fSample*` functions _define_ the scalar 3D fields; why are there to be 3 objects? `sSourcePoints` just makes the field dynamic (see `vSetTime`). The isovalue is called `fTargetValue` (see `l. 518`).

Comment: I somehow managed to render a terrain by returning fResult = (fY + noise); noise = scaled_octave_noise_3d( 3, 1, 0.5, 0, fTargetValue, fX, fY, fZ ) from the simplex perlin noise; Here's the screenshot. https://www.dropbox.com/s/j3rlltjjo13vo8h/mcubes.png . Honestly, I don't get the scalar 3D fields. Is it this one http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field? Sorry, I'm so new with this topic. Is it somewhat related to vector calculus? Btw, you're really helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: A _field_ here is any n-dim function, and _scalar_ really means _single valued_ here. And ahem, this is a QA site, no forum; so what is your exact question, or did I answer it anywhere?

Answer (score 3):

Well, Paul's source is really "spoonfed". The comment before fSample1 says:

```
//fSample1 finds the distance of (fX, fY, fZ) from three moving points
```

Basically, he is creating a so called "metaballs" object, thus he needs to "blend" three distance functions (distances from fSourcePoint[i]) into one. To do so he takes the

```
Isovalue = 1/f[0] + 1/f[1] + 1/f[2]
```

where

```
f[i] = 1/DistFromCenterToSourcePoint[i].
```

The effect is simple - when you are far from each three points, the isovalue is almost zero. The closer to the point - the lesser the f[i] and the greater your isovalue.

The distance is a usual squared euclidean distance

```
dist(p1, p2) = sqrt( (p1.x - p2.x)^2 + (p1.y - p2.y)^2 + (p1.z - p2.z)^2)
```

To achieve "Minecraft-like" isosurfaces you need to use some other metric. Take a look at taxicab (a.k.a. Manhattan) metric:

```
dist1(p1, p2) = abs(p1.x - p2.x) + abs(p1.y - p2.y) + abs(p1.z - p2.z)
```

or the max-metric

```
distMax(p1, p2) = max( abs(p1.x - p2.x), abs(p1.y - p2.y), abs(p1.z - p2.z) )
```

The "spheres" in these metrics (i.e., the sets satisfying the sphere's equation "dist = R") are cubes.

Invert them, calculate the sum (do it all in the fSample1 function), choose some typical isovalue with experiments and see the result.